# Hiding a toggle using a toggle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How could I hide a toggle from my scene and set it as non-interactable by player input by a second toggle’s “flip”. Any help is appreciated as I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you wire up a toggle you can set it to control either gameObject.SetActive() or via toggle.interactable, both ways are really easy to use